# How is it possible that in the same version of Julia, an optimizing problem has different solutions?

Tags: julia, cplex, julia-jump

Is it possible that an optimization code in the same version of Julia running on two different computers gives different solutions?
for example a code was run in a laptop and these two solutions were gained

```
[712.0, 645.0], [1515.39, 322.625], "R", "V")
 ([1515.4, 322.5], [1683.3, 0.0], "R", "V")
```

the code was run in a stronger PC but the solutions were as follow:

```
 ([712.0, 645.0], [NaN, 322.625], "R", "V")
([1515.4, 322.5], [1683.3, 0.0], "R", "V")
```

would you please help me how it can be possible,and how this problem can be solved. In this code, how NaN was happened? is there any way that the first solution will gain in the pc also? 
 Thanks for your kindly helps.

Comment: There are lots of possible answers here, and it's impossible to know which was the case without knowing more about what you're doing.  Some optimization libraries start at a random location every time.  Others use random subsets of the data at each iteration.  Your stopping condition might be time-based, and thus the faster PC was able to make its steps so small that it divided by zero.  Or more...

Comment: the code is too much long that I couldn't take here. but the libraries are same `JuMP,CPLEX,CPUTime,Plots`. would you please help me how can I remove it? is it possible to set precision of both computers similarly?

Comment: It should indeed be possible, but there's simply not enough information here to form any sort of useful answer.  Given that you're using CPLEX, you could investigate manually setting one of its many time-based and/or warm-start flags.  https://discourse.julialang.org/t/stop-julia-at-certain-optimiality-gap-and-return-decision-variables/2957/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with CPLEX it is possible to get different solutions on different computers.

Specifically, in the documentation on [determinism and the timing interface](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/progr_consid/timing/determinism_defn.html), it says:

> System time (such as CPU time measured in seconds or wall clock time
>   measured in seconds) is not deterministic; in other words, it may vary
>   from one run to another. For example, the load of other applications
>   on a system can impact performance and thus influence system time.
>   Consequently, two consecutive runs even with the same time limit may
>   yield results that are not deterministic.

If you want to improve your chances of getting deterministic results you can set a [deterministic time limit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/DetTiLim.html). However, given that you are running on two different computers (with different specs? with different operating systems?) this may still not be enough.

**EDIT:**

The link in the comments shows how to set CPLEX parameters with JuMP. For example, setting a deterministic time limit can be done, like so:

```
m = Model(with_optimizer(CPLEX.Optimizer, CPX_PARAM_DETTILIM=1000))
```

Comment: but I couldn't find any thing that can use in Julia. would you please helpe me where I can find it for Julia? Thanks.